# What happens when a stream reader isn't closed in a powershell script?

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0

I have the following powershell script that makes a web request. I noticed that I didn't close the stream reader. What happens once powershell terminates? Is garbage collected? Is a leak created?

```
[System.Net.WebResponse] $resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();
$rs = $resp.GetResponseStream();
[System.IO.StreamReader] $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $rs;
[string] $results = $sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET classes that wrap a native operating resource, like a file handle, always have a finalizer.  Which ensures that the handle will always be closed.  Even if you *terminate* Powershell with Task Manager then nothing goes wrong, the operating system ensures that any remaining handles will be closed.

The only side effect is that Powershell will keep the file open longer than necessary.  That *may* affect other processes that try to write to the file, they'll fail to obtain write access.  That could potentially be a head-scratcher.